# HTML checkbox elements are only submitted if they're checked?

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I'm trying to work on an existing website and I've found a bug, but I'm not sure why it's a bug or how to work around it.

The website basically lists some commercial properties that are for lease in one city. There's a class which grabs the listings from the database and creates an object out of each. In each object is an array of images which are associated with that property.

When the user edits a listing, they get an edit page which has a list of the images, and a "delete" checkbox next to them. The checkboxes all have the same name, so that when they are submitted back to the server, the app gets an array of the images to be deleted.

What's supposed to happen, is that the app has this array of on/off values (where on = delete), and the index of each value in the array corresponds to the index of an image in the listing object -- when one of the values is "on", the filename in the images array corresponding to that "on" value is deleted from the filesystem, and that image is removed from the database.

However, when the form is submitted, the app gets a 0-indexed array of only the checked checkboxes. So if I set three arbitrary images for deletion, the app would get

```
Array {
   [0] => "on",
   [1] => "on",
   [2] => "on"
}
```

This obviously doesn't work, the first 3 images in the listing will be deleted regardless of which checkboxes are set.

How can I fix this? I would like to avoid naming each checkbox (`delete_1`, `delete_2`, `delete_3`, etc) as the system is already built to work with all the checkboxes having the same name. Is there a way I can force all of the checkboxes to be submitted with either "on" or "off?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot force unchecked checkboxes to be submitted, but you can give them unique values (instead of "on" for all) to determine which ones are checked without changing the names.

Comment: Awesome, didn't know you could do that. Thanks a lot (will accept when allowed)

Comment: omg, it is a terrible solution and definitely not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Steve I wanted to avoid naming them all differently, since that would have to change the behavior of the backend. I didn't realize you could submit a value other than "on" or "off" though -- this would require minimal changes

Comment: @Fred Nurk: He asked: "Is there a way I can force all of the checkboxes to be submitted with either "on" or "off"?" This answer doesn't answers this, but mine does.

Comment: @zerkms could you clarify why this is a terrible answer? I'd like to know the downfalls if there are any

Comment: @fred @zerk I did ask to force them to "on" or "off" and zerkms did answer that, so I upvoted him. It just happens that this solves my problem better and seems to be a better approach in general.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to force, but you could just add a hidden right before checkbox with the same name and needed value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="delete[42]" value="off" />
<input type="checkbox" name="delete[42]" value="on" />
```

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to avoid having different names for each checkbox. Currently they are all just named `delete` and the app receives them as an array. I don't think this technique would work with them all having the same name

Comment: @Carson Myers: as I said you could give the **same name** to checkbox. It is not clear what names you have `<input type="hidden" name="delete[1]" value="off" />`. Is it better?

Comment: @Carson Myers: "I don't think this technique would work" --- why don't you try? ;-)

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood you. Right now they just all have `name="delete"`, I've never used a subscript in them before. This would work as well

Comment: +1 This is the easiest, most elegant solution. This is also the solution that some frameworks use in their HTML helpers. (like CakePHP). In fact, I would name them all `name="delete[id]"`, where `id` is the image index, and that would give your backend an already-formatted-array

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to return an array on ons and offs, then you'll need to attach a function to the form submit that will scan for all the check boxes with the given name, and put their values in the array.

In jQuery this would look something like...

```
$('#yourForm').submit(function(){
    var array = new Array();
    $('input[name="nameOfCheckboxes"]').each(function(index){
        array[index] = $(this).value();
    }
    var r = $.param(array);
    $('#someHiddenFieldInForm').value(r);
 }
```

(code is untested, of course)

Comment: +1 for valid solution, but javascript seems overkill for this problem

Comment: Do you really have nothing better to do then to complain? Carson asked for solution that didn't require changing existing "functionality". His question wasn't clear on how much he was willing to change, and using JavaScript required no changes to existing code.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this by adding the following jQuery:

```
$(function () {
  $("#myform").submit(function(){
    $("input[name='delete']:not(:checked)").attr("checked","checked").val("off");  
  });
});
```

`myform` being the ID of your form and `delete` being the name of the checkboxes.

Comment: I briefly considered using javascript, but it seemed like overkill in the situation. The accepted answer to this question involved changing `foreach($listing['delete'] as $index => $state)` to `foreach($listing['delete'] as $index)`, which I think is the ideal solution for me. +1 for valid solution though

Comment: Gert, like yours better than mine. +1

Comment: Javascript is a hack solution.

Answer (score 1):

Fred Nurk's solution is good and I upvoted it. Personally when I've had this situation, I've always given the fields different names. I use a common prefix, followed by an underscore so it's easy to recognize, and then some sort of id. I'll often make a set of fields all with the same pattern, like "name_1", "amount_1", "foobar_1", "name_2", "amount_2", etc. It's fairly easy to loop through the fields and take these names apart. (In Java, just indexOf('_').)

Answer (score 0):

The other way around this problem is to accept an oddity of HTML Forms and catch it with a local variable that employs [ternary operators](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) during declaration.

For example, given a checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="notify_users" id="notify_cb">
```

You can process the post like this regardless of the inclusion of the checkbox value:

```
// normal boolean value    
$notify_users = ((!empty($_POST['notify_users']) and $_POST['notify_users'] == 'on' );    
// explicitly set a 1 or 0
$notify_users = ((!empty($_POST['notify_users']) and $_POST['notify_users'] == 'on' )? 1 : 0);
// explicitly set 'yes' or 'no'
$notify_users = ((!empty($_POST['notify_users']) and $_POST['notify_users'] == 'on' )? 'yes' : 'no');
```

In my mind this is preferable to adding additional Javascript to the client, if only because it's a tiny bit less to maintain (and arguably clearer for a successor/other dev to grok what's going on)